# www.asp.net/learn Is gone, or it's archived somewhere?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I had a bunch of bookmark to "www.asp.net/learn/", specially the one about data-access and security. 
I was keeping them to send them to newbies.

The site seem to be wiped.

Someone found an archive???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Via forums.asp.net: [Where did the Learn page go?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1535662.aspx)

Comment: ok, for data-access it's  http://www.asp.net/web-forms/data/

Answer (score 2):

They probably just did some consolidation. The videos are still there. http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/ the same thing happened last time. give it a few days or so and they may provide links to the material.

Answer (score 1):

[Way Back Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.asp.net/learn/)

Comment: that slow!
it's better that nothing, but ther is something more handy?

Answer (score 1):

From the link http://forums.asp.net/t/1535662.aspx posted by tadmason:

> With the new site design most of the content that had been on the Learn page has moved to the new Web Forms section, or the updated MVC section.   Below please find a chart to help you find what you might be looking for:

Or as Jaxidian suggested, you could use the Way Back Machine: http://web.archive.org/web/%2a/http://www.asp.net/learn/